# Magento 2: Where are Gallery Images Processed in an Admin Save?

Tags: magento2, product, image, upload

In Magento 2, if you navigate to

```
 Products->Catalog->Edit->Images and Videos
```

you can add images to your products.  The uploader will upload a temp image immediately, and after a product save there will be appropriately sized images in `pub/media/catalog/product/cache`.

Where is the code that handles saving the product gallery image data to the database, and where is the code that handles creating the new `media` image files on disk?  The product save controller

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php
public function execute()
{
    //...
    $product = $this->initializationHelper->initialize(
        $this->productBuilder->build($this->getRequest())
    );
    $this->productTypeManager->processProduct($product);

    if (isset($data['product'][$product->getIdFieldName()])) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Unable to save product'));
    }

    $originalSku = $product->getSku();
    $product->save();
    //...
}
```

Doesn't contain anything obvious about image saving, so the code is *probably* somewhere down the `initializationHelper`, `productBuilder`, `productTypeManager`, or `save` call stacks.  I'm hoping someone here knows where this data gets saved in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php`

```
public function afterSave()
{
        ......
        // Resize images for catalog product and save results to image cache
        /** @var Product\Image\Cache $imageCache */
        if (!$this->_appState->isAreaCodeEmulated()) {
            $imageCache = $this->imageCacheFactory->create();
            $imageCache->generate($this);
        }
        ......
}
```

As we can see, the process image is in `afterSave()` method.
There are some classes handle the process image:

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php*
*vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php*

Comment: @AlanStorm `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php::saveF‌​ile()`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/266166/17154

Answer (score 0):

when you upload before save. the image was save with filename.tmp.
you should research class

> 'Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper'

with initialize and save function.

and

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler.php
>   with moveImageFromTmp function

that's  the best answer for you.

Comment: Not sure I follow this -- where in the initialization helper does data get saved to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out from here.

```
public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                ['fileId' => 'image']
            );
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
            $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
            $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
            $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $config = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config');
            $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($config->getBaseTmpMediaPath()));

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after',
                ['result' => $result, 'action' => $this]
            );

            unset($result['tmp_name']);
            unset($result['path']);

            $result['url'] = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config')
                ->getTmpMediaUrl($result['file']);
            $result['file'] = $result['file'] . '.tmp';
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $response */
        $response = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
        $response->setContents(json_encode($result));
        return $response;
    }
```

File Path :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Gallery/Upload.php

I hope useful for you.

Comment: Not sure I follow this.  The above is the upload constructor that creates the temp file -- gallery data and files aren't created until the save controller runs. Am I missing something, or did you misunderstand the question?