# Magento 2 : Missing required argument $baseTmpPath

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I used image uploader in ui form. But, when I save image not saved in main folder and return error

> Missing required argument $baseTmpPath of Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader.

My Files code :

**di.xml :**

```
<!-- Image Uploader -->
    <virtualType name="VendorModuleModelImageUploader" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">test/tmp/image</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">test/image</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">VendorModuleModelImageUploader</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <!-- End Image Uploader -->
```

**ImageUploader.php :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

/**
 * Catalog image uploader
 */
class ImageUploader {
    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Base tmp path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;

    /**
     * Base path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * Allowed extensions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $allowedExtensions;

    /**
     * ImageUploader constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     * @param string $basePath
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        $baseTmpPath,
        $basePath,
        $allowedExtensions
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Set base tmp path
     *
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath) {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set base path
     *
     * @param string $basePath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath) {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowed extensions
     *
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions) {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base tmp path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseTmpPath() {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBasePath() {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions() {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName) {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for moving and move it
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName) {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();

        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);

        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile($baseTmpImagePath, $baseImagePath);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for save and save it to tmp dir
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     *
     * @return string[]
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId) {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));

        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }

        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];

        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Save.php :**

```
private function imageSaveToDir(array $rawData) {
    $data = $rawData;
    if (isset($data['review_image'][0]['name']) && isset($data['review_image'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
        $data['review_image'] = $data['review_image'][0]['name'];
        /**  \Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader*/
        $this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($data['review_image']);
    } elseif (isset($data['review_image'][0]['image']) && !isset($data['review_image'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
        $data['review_image'] = $data['review_image'][0]['image'];
    } else {
        $data['review_image'] = null;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**DataProvider.php :**

```
if (!$this->loadedData) {
            $storeId = (int) $this->request->getParam('store');
            $this->collection->setStoreId($storeId)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $items = $this->collection->getItems();
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $itemData = $item->getData();
                $imageName = $itemData['review_image'];
                $itemData['review_image'] = array(
                    [
                        'name' => $imageName,
                        'url' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'test/image/' . $imageName,
                    ],
                );
                $item->setStoreId($storeId);
                $this->loadedData[$item->getEntityId()] = $itemData;
                break;
            }
        }
```

**Upload.php :**

```
public function execute() {
        $imageUploadId = $this->_request->getParam('param_name', 'review_image');
        try {
            $this->imageUploader->setBaseTmpPath('test/tmp/image');
            $this->imageUploader->setBasePath('test/image');
            $imageResult = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageUploadId);

            $imageResult['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $imageResult = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($imageResult);
    }
```

What I am missing here ?

Comment: add contruct method too

Comment: Which file's ? @SohelRana

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not quite right to do, but it helped me.

Use below code in file Uploader.php :

```
public function __construct(
    Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
    Filesystem $filesystem,
    UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    $baseTmpPath = self::IMAGE_TMP_PATH,
    $basePath = self::IMAGE_PATH,
    $allowedExtensions = []
) {
```

https://github.com/Maxdzy/eduMagenta2/blob/EDU270-6/app/code/Edu/CmsSimpleBadge/Model/Uploader.php

Comment: you shouldn't be overwriting core classes

Comment: Thank you so much it is also working for me. I have used my custom image uploader and as per your suggestion.